# Efficent disk I/O for logging

Tags: logging, disk

I have an application that has to log a lot of data I was wondering if it is better in terms of I/O to separate the data into files e.g. transaction logs go to one file and performance logs to separate file or is it better to write to one file (I can separate the files when I consume them later).

Will it make a difference in write latency if there are 1 file vs multiple files, which is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody will be able to tell, you need to test for yourself and consider the following:

- Are transaction logs and performance logs written from the same thread?
- The disk i/o must not be the bottleneck, otherwise it probably won't make a difference.
- The stream api (fprintf) in glibc uses internal locks, this can become a bottleneck (if i/o isn't).
- The performance of the underlying filesystem will affect this.
- If you must separate them later anyway, then it probably makes no sense to write into one file. Especially if the two have a different format.
- Premature optimization is the root of all evil.